# EFI Shell: 'mount' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or bath file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, mount, efi

I am trying to use `EFI Shell version 2.50 [5.12]` to install Linux on a windows notebook. `map -r` gives a list of devices, but I am not sure if the ubuntu usb-stick is among them. The problem is that `mount` command returns the error `'mount' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`, so I cant proceed and check which device might be the usb stick.

Comment: I've never heard that this is even possible in EFI shell. Unless you're a very experienced sysadmin I suspect you'll want to be in the graphical or at least interactive installer which comes with every "live CD" these days.

Comment: I thought that the point of EFI shell was to execute other boot loaders manually.

Comment: What EFI shell are you using and where did you get it?  Did you download it from somewhere or was it supplied by your notebook manufacturer?  `mount` [should](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/efi-shells-and-scripting/) be there.  In the meantime can you guess by entering `fs0:`, `dir`, `fs1:`, `dir` etc?  My firmware mounts USB automatically on `fs1:`.  Note you probably only see FAT partitions.